# Html5 web storage not displaying data in a second page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I am using webstorage to save data.When i get the data through form & save it in a variable (in this case 'one') and try to display in the same page , it does that correctly. But when i import the same '.js' file and try to display it in a different page, it doesn't work. How to use webstorage to retrieve the data in a different page ? Also, i don't want to use query string !

First page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="webstorageAPI.js"></script>
<link href="webstorageAPI.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <section id="leftbox">
     <section id="leftbox">
     <form action="seconddisplayfile.html" method="post">
            <p>(key) One: <input type="text" id="one"  /></p>
            <p>(value)Two:<textarea id="two"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit" id="button" value="Save"  /></p>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section id="rightbox">
     Nothing yet !
    </section>
    </section>
    


</body>
</html>
```

Second page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="webstorageAPI.js"></script>
<link href="webstorageAPI.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 
    <section id="wbox">
     Nothing yet!
    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```js
// JavaScript Document



function doFirst(){
 var button = document.getElementById("button");
 
 button.addEventListener('click',save,false);
}

function save(){
 var one = document.getElementById("one").value;  //but only contents  is to be taken not label n all
 var two = document.getElementById('two').value; 
  localStorage.setItem("one",two);  //Store in key-value pair. Anytime you use this you use if by addressing the variable ie key name.
 
 //Retriveing data n displaying stored data
 display(one); //now u hav stored two so its time to use one
}

function display(one){
 var rightbox = document.getElementById('rightbox'); //refer right box
 
 var two= localStorage.getItem("one");  //Get in key-value pair

 rightbox.innerHTML= "Name of variable:"+one+"<br/>Value:"+two;
 
 /*----Second page display-----*/
 var wbox = document.getElementById("wbox");
 wbox.innerHTML= "Name of variable:"+one+"<br/>Value:"+two;*/

}

window.addEventListener('load',doFirst,false);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#leftbox{
 float:left;
 padding:20px;
 border:3px solid #F20B84;
}

#rightbox{
 float:left;
 width:250px;
 margin-left:20px;
 padding:20px;
 border:3px solid #8E1783;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second page doen't contain any element with id `rightbox`.so

```
var rightbox = document.getElementById('rightbox');
```

will return `null`.and when try to set `innerHTML` property of `rightbox`,js will throw

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

so change your `display` to

```
function display(one){
    var rightbox = document.getElementById('rightbox'); //refer right box

    var two= localStorage.getItem("one");       //Get in key-value pair
   if(rightbox)
      rightbox.innerHTML= "Name of variable:"+one+"<br/>Value:"+two;

   /*----Second page display-----*/
   var wbox = document.getElementById("wbox");
   wbox.innerHTML= "Name of variable:"+one+"<br/>Value:"+two;*/

}
```

You have to call `display` in second page .

Comment: Nope not working..yaa i removed the comment part in .js doc...i was just cross checking whether it works using id="rightbox"...but neither of the two ids give the result in second page !

Comment: No error message...it simply doesn't give any output...Cross-tab Communication is to be applies i learnt but not understanding how to apply it

Comment: are you calling `display` function in second page.

Comment: I've imported <script src="webstorageAPI.js"></script>
in the second page too

Comment: but `display` is only called only when you click the button                  `function doFirst(){
 var button = document.getElementById("button");
 
 button.addEventListener('click',save,false);
}`. So you need to call `display`